# Replacement for source in sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh, dot-source

I need to set the environment variables,  usually we do this by

```
source script.sh
```

But now, I am automating it during the boot process and it looks like the root boots by default with `sh` shell.  How do I source this script in `sh`?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The dot command '`.`' is the equivalent of the C Shell (and Bash) `source` command.  It is specified by POSIX (see [`dot`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot)), and supported by the Bourne and Korn shells (and `zsh`, I believe).

```
. somefile
```

Note that the shell looks for the file using `$PATH`, but the file only has to be readable, not executable.

As noted in the comments below, you can of course specify a relative or absolute pathname for the file — any name containing a slash will not be searched for using `$PATH`.  So:

```
. /some/where/somefile
. some/where/somefile
. ./somefile
```

could all be used to find `somefile` if it existed in the three different specified locations (if you could replace `.` with `ls -l` and see a file listed).

<sup>*Pedants of the world unite!  Yes, if the current directory is the root directory, then `/some/where/somefile` and `./some/where/somefile` would refer to the same file — with the same real path — even without links, symbolic or hard, playing a role (and so would `../../some/where/somefile`).*</sup>

Answer (score 15):

**tl;dr** With `sh` (as opposed to `bash`) the argument must contain a slash: `source ./script.sh`, not just `source script.sh`. Unless `script.sh` can be found in `PATH`.

Dot (`.`) command exists in both `bash` and `sh`. Additionally, `bash` aliases it as `source`. From `bash` manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source

> **source**
>
> ```
> source filename
> ```
>
> A synonym for `.` (see Bourne Shell Builtins).

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_002e

> **. (a period)**
>
> ```
> . filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> Read and execute commands from the `filename` argument in the current shell context. If `filename` does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find filename. When Bash is not in POSIX mode, the current directory is searched if `filename` is not found in `$PATH`.

From [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

> If `file` does not contain a `/`, the shell shall use the search path specified by `PATH` to find the directory containing file. Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the dot utility need not be executable.