# What means a . at the beginning of a command line

Tags: linux, shell

Sorry for a maybe stupid question:
I feel I searched the whole web for an explanation.
I'd be happy to get a hint for link to get this information.

I shall execute a shell command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/ckan/lib/default/bin$ . activate
```

which leads to:

```
(default) ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/ckan/lib/default/bin$
```

What means the `.` in the beginning of the `activate` command.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732283/13507154) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/46146) might help you understand.

Comment: Thanx a lot... that helps a lot....

Comment: Thanx again... yes, thats it...